# Can you check what I understood about lua stack is right?

Tags: lua, lua-api

I'm learning lua.

I don't understand why this is wrong.

This is my lua code

```lua
-- lua
Enemy = {
  HP    = 30,
  SPEED = 8,
  POWER = 10
}
```

And this is my cpp code.
It will access to Enemy table and each value.

```cpp
...
lua_getglobal(L, "Enemy");

/*
    Current virtual stack
    -----------------------------
    [1] or [-1] Enemy table
*/

lua_pushstring(L, "HP");

/*
    Current virtual stack
    -----------------------------
    [2] or [-1] "HP"
    [1] or [-2] Enemy table
*/

lua_gettable(L, 1); // pop key("HP") and push Enemy["HP"]

/*
    Current virtual stack
    -----------------------------
    [2] or [-1] 30(Enemy["HP"])
    [1] or [-2] Enemy table
*/

// using the 30
double dHP = lua_tonumber(L, -1);

// I think that a top of the stack which is 30 will be pop.  
lua_pop(L, -1);  

/*
    Current virtual stack
    -----------------------------
    [1] or [-1] Enemy table
*/

lua_pushstring(L, "SPEED");

/*
    Current virtual stack
    -----------------------------
    [2] or [-1] "SPEED"
    [1] or [-2] Enemy table
*/

lua_gettable(L, -2);

/*
    Current virtual stack
    -----------------------------
    [2] or [-1] 8(Enemy["SPEED"])
    [1] or [-2] Enemy table
*/

// when I use a top of the stack, VS throws the error.
// lua error said that I'm attempting index a nil value. 
double dSpeed = lua_tonumber(L, -1);
```

If **lua_tonumber** pop the value, it makes sense. but there is no desc like that.
I want to know which part of stack is wrong.. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lua_pop(L, n)` pops `n` elements from the stack.
So, `lua_pop(L, -1);` is not what you want.

Comment: Oh GOD.. In this case, my English was the problem. I understood [n] element. Thank you!